# IF function data from multiple sheets paste into blank sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I do not know how to word this correctly.

I have a workbook with 7 worksheets all named differently.

I want to write an if function that will search all the worksheets, and if it matches that criteria to paste into "Name" sheet. I have tried multiple ways and cannot achieve this. This is where I will get the criteria.

```
Dim Client As String
Client = InputBox("Enter the Clients name")
```

This code works if I extract data from one sheet:

```
Dim pasteRowIndex As Long
pasteRowIndex = 2

Dim LR as Long
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For I = 2 To LR

    If Cells(I, 1).Value = Client Then


        'Now the code to grab the data and past into a new workbook
        Rows(I).Select                           'This just works on the active sheet, but I want this to iterate through
        all the sheets and paste the range into sheet2 in this code
        Selection.Copy


        'Switch to the sheet where you want to paste it & paste
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select                  'However I will change this name
        Rows(pasteRowIndex).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        'Next time you find a match, it will be pasted in a new row
        pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1


        'Switch back to your table & continue to search for your criteria
        'Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    End If

Next I
```

While the above code works for a single sheet I want the macro to iterate through all the sheets, and they are not named Sheet1-Sheet7.

Also, there must be a cleaner way of doing this.

Apologies if this is unclear, do let me know if more clarity is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may loop through all the sheets in your workbook as following sample code:

```
Dim Sht As Worksheet

For Each Sht In Worksheets
    If Sht.Name <> "Sheet1" Or Sht.Name <> "Sheet7" Then
        'Do your stuff here
        'sample code to refer the row at specific sheet without activating it
        Sht.Rows(I).Copy 
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(pasteRowIndex, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End If
Next
```

Will recommend to avoid use of .Select and .Activate method. Instead use Worksheet variable to refer to the specific sheet.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response. I am unsure how to apply the `if Cells(I, 1).Value = Client then` to each sheet. Sorry, I am having a brain fart today.

Comment: use if 'Sht.Cells(I, 1).Value = Client Then' to refer to each sheet. The line should be within Sheet loop.

Comment: `For Each Sht In Worksheets
    If Sht.Name <> "Sheet1" Or Sht.Name <> "Sheet7" Then
        
        For I = 2 To LR
        'Do your stuff here
            If Sht.Cells(I, 1).Value = Client Then

        'sample code to refer the row at specific sheet without activating it
                Sht.Rows(I).Copy
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(pasteRowIndex, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            End If
        Next I
    End If
Next
`   Is my loop, however it is infinite. And it didn't iterate through all the sheets...

Comment: The 'For Each Sht' loop cannot be infinitive and will run for each sheet in the workbook including hidden sheets. However your inner loop 'For I = 2 To LR' might be taking longer time if they are enough in numbers. Can you share your updated code? May be it will help in identifying your current issue.